# How can i Merge these two php scripts into one

Tags: php

for my magento i have 2 scripts to copy the description to a other storeview.

Script 1.
Copies/merges the description from store 1 and 2 to storeview 6

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_DescMerge extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    const STORE_ID_1 = 1; // Replace this with correct value
    const STORE_ID_2 = 2; // Replace this with correct value
    const STORE_DESTINATION = 6; // Replace this with correct value

    public function run()
    {
        $catalogResourceModel = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
        $catalogAction = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');


        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();

            if($product->getId() >= 29932)
            {


                echo "Updating product $productId\n";

                $descrStore1 = $catalogResourceModel
                    ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'description', static::STORE_ID_1);

                $descrStore2 = $catalogResourceModel
                    ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'description', static::STORE_ID_2);


                $attrs = array(
                    'description' => $descrStore1.'<br />'.$descrStore2,

                );

                $catalogAction
                    ->updateAttributes(array($productId), $attrs, static::STORE_DESTINATION);
            }   
            else {}
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_DescMerge();
$shell->run();
```

Then i have a separte files which copies the description from storeview 2 to storeview 3.

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_DescMerge extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    const STORE_ID_2 = 2; // Replace this with correct value
    const STORE_DESTINATION = 3; // Replace this with correct value

    public function run()
    {
        $catalogResourceModel = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
        $catalogAction = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');


        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();

        if($product->getId() >= 29932)
        {


            echo "Updating product $productId\n";

            $descrStore2 = $catalogResourceModel
                ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'description', static::STORE_ID_2);


            $attrs = array(
                'description' => $descrStore2,
            );

            $catalogAction
                ->updateAttributes(array($productId), $attrs, static::STORE_DESTINATION);
        }   
        else {}
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_DescMerge();
$shell->run();
```

I run these scripts every few days.
How can i merge these 2 scripts into one. Which should be much more efficient ....

Answer (score 0):

passing an array with run method and use it instead of static::STORE_ID_* also static::STORE_DESTINATION need to pass with another parameter of run method. another note - you need to change $attrs['description'] variable properly on the base of static::STORE_ID_*

Comment: My php knowledge doesn't reach that far. Can you help me with this?